# How to access a fields inside values from filtering query sets in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

my code is like this:

*#user model*

```
class User(models.Model):
     phonenum = PhoneNumberField()
```

*#bio model*

```
class Bio(models.Model):
    user_num = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_num_bio')
```

*#view.py*

```
result = Bio.objects.filter(user_num__phonenum__national_number__endswith=7896)
```

I want to access the national_number that is a value of PhoneNumberField, but the last line gives error:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup '_national_number_endswith' for PhoneNumberField or join on the field not permitted.
```

## INFO:

PhoneNumberField values:

```
PhoneNumber(country_code=98, national_number=1234567896, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=20, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
```

package_add: [PhoneNumberField](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field)

Comment: Since this `PhoneNumberField` does not belong to Django, you must add the corresponding reference to the package that you are using

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I added the link, https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field.

Comment: try using  **national_number__endswith**, 
double underscore befor "endswith"

Comment: @SachinWhitemanD that already has two underscores.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need redo or find other way to do:

```
result = Bio.objects.filter(user_num__phonenum__national_number__endswith=7896)
```

As can i see, django-phonenumber-field it's an interface for python-phonenumbers https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers an "national_number" its part of python-phonenumbers and not accessible from django-phonenumber.

Comment: what do yo mean by redo?

Comment: Maybe not use "national_number", this attribute it's not part of django-phonenumber-field.